# Two questions in the predicate calculus system

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am reading A.G.Hamilton's *Logic for Mathematicians*I am stuck at proposition 4.25 :Let A and B be wfs. of L

(i)If $x_i$ does not occur free in A ，then $$\vdash ((\forall x_i)(A \to B)\leftrightarrow (A\to (\forall x_i)B))$$ and
$$\vdash ((\exists x_i)(A \to B)\leftrightarrow (A \to (\exists x_i)B))$$

(ii) if $x_i$ does not occur free in B, then $$\vdash ((\forall x_i)(A\to B)\leftrightarrow ((\exists x_i)A \to B))$$ and $$\vdash ((\exists x_i)(A \to B) \leftrightarrow ((\forall x_i)A \to B))$$

I am confused with the second and the fourth.

The system's axioms are as follows:

(K1) $(A \to (B \to A))$

(K2)$(A \to (B\to C))\to ((A\to B)\to (A \to C))$

(K3)$(\neg A \to \neg B)\to (B\to A)$

(K4)$((\forall x_i) A\to A)$,if $x_i$ does not occur free in A

(K5)$((\forall x_i)A(x_i) \to A(t))$,if $A(x_i)$is a wf. of L and t is a term in L which is free for $x_i$ in $A(x_i)$

(K6) $(\forall x_i)(A\to B)\to (A\to (\forall x_i)B)$,if A contains no free occurrence of the variable $x_i$
Additionally, we have MP(Modus ponens) and Generalisation.

Perhaps this result can be helpful(casue the author mentioned it):$$\vdash ((\forall x_i)(A \to B)\to ((\exists x_i) A \to (\exists x_i)B))$$

I would appreciate it very much if you could help me.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the second formula of (ii):

*(1)* $\exists x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ --- premise

*(2)* $\lnot \exists x \beta \to \exists x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ --- from Axiom (K1) and (1) by *MP*

*(3)* $\alpha$ --- assumed

*(4)* $\lnot \exists x \beta$ --- assumed

*(5)* $\lnot \lnot \forall x \lnot \beta$ --- abbreviation for $\exists$

*(6)* $\forall x \lnot \beta$ --- by *Double Negation* (page 36)

*(7)* $\lnot \beta$ --- from (6) and Axiom (K4) by *MP*

*(8)* $\lnot (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ --- from (3) and (7), using the *tautology* $\alpha \rightarrow (\lnot \beta \rightarrow \lnot (\alpha \rightarrow \beta))$ and *MP*

*(9)* $\forall x \lnot (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ --- by **Gen Th** ($x \notin FV(\alpha)$)

*(10)* $\lnot \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ --- abbreviation

*(11)* $\lnot \exists x \beta \to \lnot \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ --- from (4) and (10) by *DT*

*(12)* $\lnot \lnot \exists x \beta$ --- using (2) and (11) and tautology page 39

*(13)* $\exists x \beta$ --- by *Double Negation* (page 36)

*(14)* $\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \beta$ --- from (2) by *Deduction Theorem*.

In conclusion we have:

> $\exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \vdash (\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \beta)$.

---

*(1)* $\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \beta$ --- assumed

*(2)* $\forall x \lnot (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ --- assumed

*(3)* $\alpha \land \lnot \beta$ --- from (2) and Axiom (K4) and using tautological equivalence

*(4)* $\lnot \beta$ --- from (3)

*(5)* $\forall x \lnot \beta$ --- by the **Generalization Theorem**, because $x$ is not free in assumptions (1) and (2)

*(6)* $\lnot \exists x \beta$ --- abbreviation

*(7)* $\alpha$ --- from (3)

*(8)* $\exists x \beta$ --- from (1) by *MP*.

Having derived the contradiction [with (6) and (8)], we apply again the schema above (page 39) for managing contradiction
to get :

*(9)* $\lnot \forall x \lnot (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, that is : $\exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$.

In conclusion we have :

> $(\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \beta) \vdash  \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$.

---

---

The other formula must be treated similarly.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't realize the way to tackle contridicition before!! The answer is quite enlightening!

Comment: @ziyehuang - you are welcome :-)